# jQgrid pagination is not showing next page when i am reloading the grid on server side filter

Tags: free-jqgrid

jQgrid pagination is not showing me the next page when i am reloading the grid on server side filter.

i am doing server side filter so calling database on each filter applied to the grdi and get records and finally reload the grid to show the updated data . Which is fine but grid client side pagination is not showing next page data

```
jQuery("#" + gridId).jqGrid('setGridParam', {
        datatype: 'json',
        loadonce:true,
        postData: { PageSize: pgSize, PageNo: pgNumber, FilterQuery: $("#" + hdnFilterSqlQuery).val(), SortQuery: sortSqlQuery },
        serializeGridData: function (postData) {
            return JSON.stringify(postData);
        }
    }).trigger('reloadGrid', { fromServer: true });
```

Comment: I'm not sure, which scenario you use and which version of jqGrid. If you really use [free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid), which support `` then you could add `page: pgNumber` property together with `fromServer: true`. You don't need to reset `datatype: 'json', loadonce: true` and `serializeGridData` once more if you included the option in the grid previously.

Comment: i am  doing server side filter so calling database on each filter applied to the grdi and get records and finally reload the grid to show the updated data . Which is fine but grid client side pagination is not showing next page data .

Comment: Could you answer on the following questions: **which version of jqGrid you use and from which fork of jqGrid?** How many rows will be returned on the last request (to get filtered data) to the server? Which value has `rowNum`? It would be helpful if you include the code of jqGrid, which you use. Some people, for example use always TreeGrid, data grouping, virtual scrolling (`scroll: 1`) and so on and don't inform about that in his question. You gives almost no information about jqGrid, thus I have to guess what you do.

Comment: Hi Oleg, Thanks for your reply i am using JqGrid JS - v5.2.0 , My grid is serverside filter and client side pagination for 10,000 rows every page load . i have provided two event in each control for filter (tab event and enter key press event).  for Tab Event pagination is working but enter key event pagination is not working.